# Method Calculate User Answers

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am writing spring hibernate app to make online test and this method for calculating user grade I have one to many relations between multi-choice question and answer.

Also, please check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656908/what-is-better-in-performance-make-bulk-call-to-db-or-single-call-on-loop-for-c)

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    QuestionRepository questionRepository;

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    Transformer transformer;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void correctAnswer(List<StudentAnswersDTO> questionAnswers) {
        logger.info("****** start correct answers ********");
        Long grade = 0L;
        List<QuestionRightAnswerDTO> rightAnswerDTOS = questionRepository.getRightAnswers();
        for (StudentAnswersDTO questionAnswer : questionAnswers) {
            if (questionAnswer.getType().toLowerCase().equals(AppConstants.MULTI_CHOICE)) {
                if (isCorrectAnswer(questionAnswer.getId(), questionAnswer.getAnswerId(), rightAnswerDTOS))
                    grade++;
            }
        }

        User currentStudent = userRepository.findByMobileNumber(SecurityHelper.getCurrentUser());
        ((Student) currentStudent).setGrade(grade);
        ((Student) currentStudent).setStudentAnswers(transformer.transform(questionAnswers, AnswerSelected.class));

        logger.info("****** end correct answers ********");
    }


    private boolean isCorrectAnswer(Long id, Long answerId, final List<QuestionRightAnswerDTO> rightAnswerDTOS) {
        for (QuestionRightAnswerDTO rightAnswer : rightAnswerDTOS) {
            if (id.equals(rightAnswer.getQuestionId()) && answerId.equals(rightAnswer.getAnswerId()))
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fist of all I will recommend you to use Constructor based dependency injection. Then I can not see the relation between the `Question, QuestionAnswer, and QuestionRightAnswer` entities... currently you are selecting all the right answers from the DB which you should NOT do! You have to get all the correct answers for this question only. Use the `question.id` from `QuestionAnswer` just to match the `QuestionRightAnswer.questionId` `FK`. Also you do take care of the `MULTI_CHOICE` questions only, but why?

Consider an implementation such as:

```
@Service
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    QuestionRepository questionRepository;
    UserRepository userRepository;
    Transformer transformer;

    @Autowired
    public NotificationService(QuestionRepository questionRepository,
                               UserRepository userRepository,
                               Transformer transformer) {
        this.questionRepository = questionRepository;
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.transformer = transformer;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public void correctAnswer(List<StudentAnswersDTO> questionAnswers) {
        logger.info("****** start correct answers ********");
        Long grade = questionAnswers
            .stream()
            .filter(questionAnswer -> questionAnswer.getType().toLowerCase().equals(AppConstants.MULTI_CHOICE))
            .filter(questionAnswer -> questionRepository
                .getRightAnswersByQuestionId(questionAnswer.getId())
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(rightAnswer -> questionAnswer.getAnswerId().equals(rightAnswer.getAnswerId())))
            .count();

        User currentStudent = userRepository.findByMobileNumber(SecurityHelper.getCurrentUser());
        ((Student) currentStudent).setGrade(grade);
        ((Student) currentStudent).setStudentAnswers(transformer.transform(questionAnswers, AnswerSelected.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks dbl for your comment it really helps me. I found out if I convert list of right answers to map this will enhance the performance

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>         User currentStudent = userRepository.findByMobileNumber(SecurityHelper.getCurrentUser());
>         ((Student) currentStudent).setGrade(grade);
> ```

Why not just say

```
        Student currentStudent 
            = (Student) userRepository.findByMobileNumber(SecurityHelper.getCurrentUser());
        currentStudent.setGrade(grade);
```

Then you don't have to keep repeating the cast.